# Matlab Project assistance to measure which method is more optimal, running or walking in the rain

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a program with matlab where I can measure which method is more optimal, running or walking in the rain.

My approach: to create a 2D meshgrid that will have a for loop going through it through a square indexed portion of it across the x-axis, with the meshgrid being the rain drops and the square shape indexing representing a "square" person going through the rain.

My problem: I am not sure about how to count what "raindrops" the indexing will be skipping if i were to add some velocity to the object as if it is running. an equation for adding velocity to it would also be handy if anyone has any ideas

Also any code examples similar to what i am doing would be very helpful! I really want to get this done

below is what loop i am using at the moment, i feel like it should be done in a  more efficient way than i am using it.

```
[X,Y]= meshgrid(1:50,1:100);

grid = [X,Y];

it=1;
time= 5;

for i= 0:time 
it= it+1;

square= grid(14:20,1+it:2+it)

end
```

This is resembling a box of 6ft in height and 2ft in width moving along the x axis at 1 unit per second for 5 seconds

Comment: Don't you have to model the raindrops differently? If there is a raindrop at every coordinate in the grid, a square moving through will collect all of them, no matter the speed. The model also does not account for raindrops falling. How about this: keep the person (rectangle) stationary and rather vary the angle and speed of raindrops?

Comment: I think this really is a 3D problem since, as zeeMonkeez suggests, rain on every tile will be hit the same at any speed! If the rain in angled more toward the person (running into it) then they will be hit by more. See this *math*.stackexchange answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/154221/283393, it should give you an idea about which parameters you need to model if you pursue solving this numerically :)